# ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick with multiple binary data in PHP

Tags: php, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

GM supports passing in binary data from standard input like this:

```
gm convert gif:- jpg:-
```

I'm trying to create a watermark using one image on top of another image using gm composite:

```
gm composite -geometry +0+0 orig.jpg watermark.jpg new.jpg
```

However, in my PHP code, I have two strings, $orig_str and $watermark_str, both are binary data of orig.jpg and watermark.jpg respectively. I'm trying to run the above by passing in these two strings as stdin, but can't figure out a way to do so.

Modifying $orig_str is fine.

I'm executing GM without using PHP's GM plugin for architecture reasons. Instead, I'm doing something like this to run gm:

```
$img = "binary_data_here";
$cmd = ' gm convert gif:- jpg:-';
$stdout = execute_stdin($cmd, $img);

function execute_stdin($cmd, $stdin /* $arg1, $arg2 */) {...}
```

Does anyone know how to do this for more than one inputs in stdin?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for [`proc_open`](http://php.net/proc_open)!

You'll pass it the command to run, then array containing descriptions of streams to open to represent stdin, stdout and stderr for the process.

The streams are effectively filehandles, so you can simply write to them as if you were writing to a file.

For example, from the printing bits in my own codebase:

```
// In this case, $data is a PDF document that we'll feed to
// the stdin of /usr/bin/lp
    $data = '';
    $handles = array(
        0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
        1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
        2 => array("pipe", "a")   // stderr is a file to write to
    );
// Setting of $server, $printer_name, $options_flag omitted...
    $process_name = 'LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/lp -h %s -d %s %s';
    $command = sprintf($process_name, $server, $printer_name, (string)$options_flag);
    $pipes = array();
    $process = proc_open($command, $handles, $pipes);
// $pipes now looks like this:
// 0 => writeable handle connected to child stdin
// As we've been given data to write directly, let's kinda like do that.
    fwrite($pipes[0], $data);
    fclose($pipes[0]);
// 1 => readable handle connected to child stdout
    $stdout = fgets($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);
// 2 => readable handle connected to child stderr
    $stderr = fgets($pipes[2]);
    fclose($pipes[2]);
// It is important that you close any pipes before calling
// proc_close in order to avoid a deadlock
    $return_value = proc_close($process);
```

Comment: Hmm... How do I use file handles with GraphicsMagick? It seems that GM takes filenames, not file handles.

Comment: Hmm.  I thought the question was "how do I start an external process and feed data to it's stdin."  Is it actually "how do I feed image data to GraphicsMagick via stdin?"  In that case, I actually have no idea, assuming that the above code doesn't actually invoke the program properly.  Now that I think about it more, how do you plan to feed *two* files to it via stdin?  Maybe you should just write the two files to disk instead?  [`tempnam`](http://php.net/tempnam) (no e!) would come in handy.